# how to get length of audio in minutes and seconds in android

Tags: java, android, c, android-layout, github

```
int duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration(); 
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvduration); textView.setText(duration);
```

Comment: duration shows in miliseconds by this method but i want to show duration of audio like 15minutes:32seconds

Comment: Please do some research first don't you know how to convert milliseconds to seconds or minute?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getDuration()):

> the duration in milliseconds, if no duration is available (for
>   example, if streaming live content), -1 is returned.

That's why you will get from `getDuration()` the duration in milliseconds.
You can use this to get the time of `MediaPlayer` as String:

```
int duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
String time = String.format("%02d min, %02d sec", 
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration) - 
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration))
);
```

And then as you write in your question:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvduration); 
textView.setText(time);
```

Comment: Y should you set "duration" again to textView?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliseconds) {
        String finalTimerString = "";
        String secondsString = "";

        //Convert total duration into time
        int hours = (int) (milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        int minutes = (int) (milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60);
        int seconds = (int) ((milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) % (1000 * 60) / 1000);
        // Add hours if there
        if (hours == 0) {
            finalTimerString = hours + ":";
        }

        // Pre appending 0 to seconds if it is one digit
        if (seconds == 10) {
            secondsString = "0" + seconds;
        } else {
            secondsString = "" + seconds;
        }

        finalTimerString = finalTimerString + minutes + ":" + secondsString;

        // return timer string
        return finalTimerString;
    }
```

Comment: my problem is solved in previous message. so thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

It's 3 years old but nobody responded correctly then I gonna response

```
public String format(long millis) {
    long allSeconds = millis / 1000;
    int allMinutes;
    byte seconds, minutes, hours;
    if (allSeconds >= 60) {
        allMinutes = (int) (allSeconds / 60);
        seconds = (byte) (allSeconds % 60);
        if (allMinutes >= 60) {
            hours = (byte) (allMinutes / 60);
            minutes = (byte) (allMinutes % 60);
            return String.format(Locale.US, "%d:%d:" + formatSeconds(seconds), hours, minutes, seconds);
        } else
            return String.format(Locale.US, "%d:" + formatSeconds(seconds), allMinutes, seconds);
    } else
        return String.format(Locale.US, "0:" + formatSeconds((byte) allSeconds), allSeconds);
}

public String formatSeconds(byte seconds) {
    String secondsFormatted;
    if (seconds < 10) secondsFormatted = "0%d";
    else secondsFormatted = "%d";
    return secondsFormatted;
}
```

millis / 1000 convert millis to seconds. Example:

```
allSeconds = 68950 / 1000 = 68 seconds
```

If allSeconds are greater than 60, we will separate the minutes from seconds, then we will convert allSeconds = 68 to minutes using:

```
minutes = allSeconds / 60 = 1 left 8
```

The numbers that left will be the seconds

```
seconds = allSeconds % 60 = 8
```

The method formatSeconds(byte seconds) adds a zero whether the seconds are less than 10.

So in the end It will be:  `1:08`

Why bytes? Long has a bad perform, then it's better use bytes for longer operations.